# compare 2 array and remove items

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, array-splice

in vue i have an array with this data(TempId):

```
[{"id":47},{"id":45},{"id":48}]
```

and second array with this:

```
 multiprices: [
    {
        id: 45,
        name: "",
        price: "2600000",
    },
    {
        id: 46,
        name: "",
        price: "2600000",
    },
    {
        id: 47,
        name: "",
        price: "2600000",
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "",
        price: "2600000",
    }
],
```

i want to find and remove the items of second array and copy them to new data.(in this example just id 46)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the second array with the condition of element is in the id list of first array

```js
const tempObj = [{ id: 47 }, { id: 45 }, { id: 48 }]
const tempId = tempObj.map(({ id }) => id)

const multiprices = [
  {
    id: 45,
    name: "",
    price: "2600000",
  },
  {
    id: 46,
    name: "",
    price: "2600000",
  },
  {
    id: 47,
    name: "",
    price: "2600000",
  },
  {
    id: 48,
    name: "",
    price: "2600000",
  },
]

const res = multiprices.filter((multiprice) => !tempId.includes(multiprice.id))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: console.log(res) return the data of 45,47,48 i need inverse of this only 46

Comment: const res = this.multiprices.filter((multiprice) => !tempId.includes(multiprice.id))
this the answer

Comment: another question is,this snippet work very well  in my localhost but not working on the server! how this possible?this is javascript!!!